# How do I seed mongodb with data from an external API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to learn NodeJS. I'm using mongoose & mLab. I'm new to every one of these technologies.

My model at the moment looks like this. I will add a few things to the schema later.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fetchData = require("../seed");

const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const dataSchema = new Schema({});

module.exports = recallData = mongoose.model("recalls", dataSchema);
```

I also made a seed file for fetching data..

```
const Recall = require("./models/Recall");

 module.exports = function getData(req, res) {
  const urls = [url1, url2, url3];

  urls.map(url => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>
        data.results.map(recalls => {
          let recs = new Recall(recalls);
          recs.save;
        })
      );
  });
}
```

my question is how do I make the fetch run and populate the database? Is there a command or a mongoose function that will do that?
I know that I'm basically trying to emulate Rails with a seed file. Maybe it's not the way to do it in Node. Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want to implement the APIs.

Comment: Yes. I want to implement a restful api with select data from the external api.

Comment: Then, you should browse through as how to implement rest apis. There are many docs available. Just do a google search.

Comment: this is kludgy but , your 'seed.js'  could just log /print to stdout the json you are mapping to recs.save. make a bash shell that uses curl to POST each json line in stdout to new object of class ' Recall' to the CRUD endpoint in mlab for inserting to 'Recall'

Comment: @eduPeeth rest apis technically isn't a problem. I'm just confused about how to seed the db with data coming in from an external api.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I was thinking of something like that. Make a json file from the fetch. and somehow seed the db with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's pretty simple. All I needed was a nights sleep. I needed to connect to mongoose and after `save()`, disconnect.

Now the code looks like this. I still need to add and edit some stuffs in it. Any smart refactoring advice is appreciated.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Recall = require("./models/Recall");
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const URLS = require("./config/seedURLs");

let resultData;
let saveCounter = 0;

mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("mongodb connection success"))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

URLS.map(async url => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    resultData = [...json.results];

    for (let i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++) {
      let temp = new Recall({
        key1: resultData[i].key1,
        key2: resultData[i].key2,
        .
        .
        .
      });

      temp.save(() => {
        saveCounter++;
        if (saveCounter === resultData.length) {
          mongoose
            .disconnect()
            .then(() => console.log("mongodb disconnected"))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**Run node seed.js command.**
This is the general idea.